# Problem with wireless networking for ubuntu server on a Raspberry pi 4

Tags: networking, server, raspberrypi

So I recently bought a raspberry pi, and I am trying to install ubuntu server 20.04 on it. I can't seem to configure wireless networking. I've tried editing the 50-cloud-init.yaml file and it doesn't seem to work. I've googled my issue and haven't been able to fix it.

50-cloud-init.yaml looks as follows

```
network:
   ethernets:
       eth0:
           dhcp4: true
           optional: true
       wlan0:
           access-points:
               "newgateway_5GHz":
                  password: "clearfield"
           version: 2
```

When I run `sudo netplan --debug try` I get the message `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:12:13: Error in network definition: unknown key 'access-points'`
I've edited the file in many different ways, I've used `sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` to edit the file as well as after installing it, as well as opening the partition on the sd card and went to network-config and changed it that way.

I've googled my problem and I've had no, luck any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the examples on [netplan.io](https://netplan.io/examples/), I would assume your file should look something like this:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                "my_ssid":
                    password: "my_password"
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
```

3 obvious errors in your file was:

1. that `version: 2` had incorrect indentation,
2. that you defined
   your AP under the `ethernets` section, where it should be under the
   `wifis` section, and
3. that you missed the `dhcp4: true` statement
   for your wifi.

In addition, you might need to run these commands:

```
sudo systemctl enable wpa_supplicant
sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

I hope this works out.

Comment: I'm currently trying it but it's not looking good I've rebooted a couple of times and at boot, i get the message   A start job is running for Wait for Network to be Configured. Then it fails

Comment: Try adding `optional: true` to your wlan0 adapter as well.

Comment: Alternatively, there may be [other solutions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972215/a-start-job-is-running-for-wait-for-network-to-be-configured-ubuntu-server-17-1), for startup jobs waiting for network connection.

Comment: That fixed the stalled boot but still no wifi connection.

Comment: Possibly see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291424/failed-to-start-netplan-wpa-wlan0-sevice-unit-netplan-wpa-wlan0-service-not-fou) for more troubleshooting with wpa_supplicant and netplan-wpa service.

Comment: okay I'll try that and get back to you, thanks for your help

Comment: Running through that steps on that thread got it working thank you so much for your help

Comment: Good to hear. I added those commands to my answer as well, so please accept it as solved. Thanks.

Comment: I'm new to this site how do I do that?