# netplan conflicts when changing AP when rederer: NetworkManager

Tags: networking, network-manager, netplan, systemd-networkd

I'm having some problems setting up the "access-points": in `netplan` , when the renderer:
NetworkManager .
My yaml is

```
cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    wlp58s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "VCRoom065":
          password: "xxXXxx"
```

When I

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
sudo netplan --debug apply
```

```
** (generate:1259): DEBUG: 18:58:22.019: Processing input file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml..
** (generate:1259): DEBUG: 18:58:22.019: starting new processing pass
** (generate:1259): DEBUG: 18:58:22.020: wlp58s0: adding wifi AP 'VCRoom065'
** (generate:1259): DEBUG: 18:58:22.020: Generating output files..
** (generate:1259): DEBUG: 18:58:22.020: networkd: definition wlp58s0 is not for us (backend 2)
(generate:1259): GLib-DEBUG: 18:58:22.020: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested) 

DEBUG: no netplan generated networkd configuration exists
DEBUG: netplan generated NM configuration exists, restarting NM
DEBUG: wlp58s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets: {}
  vlans: {}
  wifis:
    wlp58s0:
      access-points:
        VCRoom065:
          password: xXXxxXX
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true

DEBUG: Skiping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG: {}
DEBUG: netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG: netplan triggering .link rules for wlp58s0
```

If I go and check `ip addr` I'm connected to my previous AP .
I have followed the instructions in here and got some advatanges
[Failed to start netplan-wpa-wlan0.sevice: Unit netplan-wpa-wlan0.service not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291424/failed-to-start-netplan-wpa-wlan0-sevice-unit-netplan-wpa-wlan0-service-not-fou)

If I

```
sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant
sudo shutdown now
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

It does solve the problem for `renderer: networkd` but for `renderer: NetworkManager` it doesn't.
I have tried disabling `sudo systemctl stop systemd-networkd` in order to sanitise the problem.

Any ideas?.

Thank you

Comment: I suggest that you use netplan OR Ntework Manager, not both. Mix and match almost never works.

Comment: Well 'netplan' should work on top of either 'networkd' or 'NetworkManager' if this is not troubleshootable then we have a bug, but the package is meant to do that function

Comment: When netplan works correctly with NM, its default is: "Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system" That's exactly what I recommend that you do.

Comment: Well I havent read that in the manual of 'netplan' or any documentation. I want to standarise my network managing workflow in Linux been able to do it with a text file. I cant do that with 'nmcli' although I also like it.  This is a question to troubleshoot a software/config issue. I dont get the point of coming here saying A is not working, get the response of "then use B" I want to use A, lets see what is wrong with A or your config.

Comment: I didn't suggest that you use B. I suggested that you not try to simultaneously use A and B together. netplan is typically used in servers without a desktop environment. NM is typically used in desktop installations. My advice was to pick one or the other, not both. If you want to use netplan *only*, then I shall propose an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have previously set this interface up directly through NetworkManager, and therefore you have conflicting configuration under /etc/NetworkManager.  Try removing that config and trying again.

Comment: Thanks , I have just seen that I had a config file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/previousSSID.nmconnection` . I have moved it to other location . Now `netplan --debug generate` `netplan --debug apply` , and the interface doesn't get no DHCP lease

Comment: What does `iwconfig wlp58s0` show in this case?